# studio sound card

Tags: sound

I had to migrate from Windows to Linux for a number of reasons.
Now my sound card driver for Linux does not exist.
I use the Dynacord 600-3 mixer as a sound card.
And drivers are only available for Windows and Mac.
My job depends on your guidance.
Please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks .mooseeyoo.

Answer (score 0):

you tried 'ALSA' and 'jackaudio connection kit'?

which DAW do you use?

the versions of jack audio are out of date, hoping they integrate the 'up to date' once.
you can take a look at 'rncbc' site, he is the maker of these content. he have also .deb packages on githaub, you can install via 'Eddy' but run not perfectly.

the 600-3 is an USB interface, that has 'class compliant mode'?

Greets
Muuhman